# Type 'str' doesn't have expected attribute '__setitem__' in Python

Tags: python, string, attributes

Why do I get "**Type 'str' doesn't have expected attribute '__setitem__'**" when I call my static class method?

```
@staticmethod
def replace_region_decimal_sign(to_convert):
    to_convert[to_convert.index(',')] = '.'  # Replace comma ("region" decimal sign) with a dot
    return to_convert
```

[image]

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Calculator.replace_region_decimal_sign("1,23"))
```

[image]

Comment: "Why do I get `Type 'str' doesn't have expected attribute '__setitem__'` when I call my static class method?" Because you try to pass a `str` when you call the method, and your method expects the thing that you passed to have `__setitem__`, and a `str` does not have it. If you expected that it should be possible to modify a string in-place, you cannot; please see the linked duplicate for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are inmutable in Python, therefore they can't be changed and don't implement `__setitem__`.

Try something like:

```
i = to_convert.index(',')
to_convert = to_convert[:i] + '.' + to_convert[i+1:]
```

This generates a new string.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination of the error message...